# pywinauto - maybe too many control clause can not find element

Tags: python, pywinauto

In `pywinauto==0.6.3`, `self.Select_All_Templates.click_input()` has a COMError. When I upgrade to 0.6.4 version, the COMError disappears but I get an ElementNotFound error, but a `print_control_identifiers` call shows that child_windows is correct. when I delete all list in the grid, and run the code again, error is gone.
[my GUI--picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6yJW.png)

`pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'control_type': 'CheckBox', 'title': 'Select All Templates', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo - '', , None>, 'backend': u'uia'}`

```
class Pywin(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = application.Application(backend="uia")

    def controlor(self):
        self.about_dlg = self.app.window(class_name="Qt5QWindowIcon")
        self.Select_All_Templates = self.about_dlg["Pane"].child_window(title="Select All Templates", control_type="CheckBox")
        # self.Select_All_Templates = self.about_dlg["Select All Templates"]


    def dlg(self):

        # self.Select_All_Templates.wrapper_object().click_input()
        self.Select_All_Templates.click_input()


    def connect(self, window_name):
        self.app.connect(path = window_name)
        time.sleep(1)



if __name__ ==  "__main__":
    app = Pywin()
    tool_name = "FingerPrint EVK Client *"
    window_name = r"E:\EVK\EVK\FingerPrintEVK_V1.19.10 Beta20\FingerPrintEVK_V1.19.10 Beta20.exe"

    app.connect(window_name)
    app.controlor()
    app.dlg()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the picture when I delete all list in the grid, and run the code again, error is gone."? What does the picture show?

Comment: sorry for my mistake, I upload a picture of my gui , there are 1200 lists (600 Temples + 600 Samples)  like `control_type="Header"` in the grid (like the picture shows),  in this situation, I got the ElementNotFound error, but when I delete all list in my gui, the code can run well

Comment: What is the part of `print_control_identifiers` output for this particular check box?

Comment: @Vasily Ryabov first, the code runs well, the `print_control_identifiers` output looks every thing is right ,and the check box can be cilcked, but when I run the code again, the `print_control_identifiers` only output: 
  `Control Identifiers:


Pane - 'FingerPrint EVK Client V1.19.10 Beta20'    (L674, T46, R1924, B766)
[u'FingerPrint EVK Client V1.19.10 Beta20', u'FingerPrint EVK Client V1.19.10 Beta20Pane', 'Pane']
child_window(title="FingerPrint EVK Client V1.19.10 Beta20", control_type="Pane")`.    in this time, the ElementNotFound Error happend .

Comment: when error happend, I have 2 ways to make it works normal : 1. delete all list in the grid，run the code again. 2. restart my application, run the code again.

Comment: Are you running the script as Administrator? If not, that might be the reason. We're working to print warnings in case of insufficient rights for next release. Currently it's silent.

Comment: Has running as Administrator helped?

Comment: no, it didn't work. now I use `wrapper_object()` method to get some  wrapper and insert it into python list when initialize, use this python list control click . in this way runs well except can not get the widget status